# The graph of $y = (x-1)(x+1)(x+2)$ contains $(a,b)$. If $-1\leq a\leq 1$, which is NOT a possible value of $b$? ($-2$, $-1$, $0$, $1$)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $$y = (x-1)(x+1)(x+2)$$
>
> The graph in the $xy$-plane of the equation above contains the point $(a,b)$. if $-1 \leq a \leq 1$, which of the following is NOT a possible value of $b$?
>
> A) $-2 \qquad$ B) $-1 \qquad$ C)  $0 \qquad$ D)  $1$

The range of $a$ is given as $[-1,1]$ and we are asked to find the value of $b$ when a is defined in that range, right? If that's the case, I'm left with either B) or D) as the answers and the answer is D).

Can someone tell me if I'm missing something here?

Comment: I am not clear why you excluded A as a "not possible value" before you excluded B.  The question is essentially what values can $y$ take or not take when $x$ is in the interval from $-1$ through to $+1$

Comment: @Henry I think the OP used the integer values in the interval to find some elements in the range , and $y=-2$ at $x=0$ (so $A$ is eliminated) , along with $y=0$ at $x=-1,+1$ (so $C$ is eliminated). So that leaves B,D.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon - possibly so.  I instantly thought if there was a single answer it must be an extreme value. But if you have eliminated $A$ and $C$ then you could then use a continuity argument (intermediate value theorem) to say $y=-1$ for some $x$ in the interval (in fact at least two of them) so that eliminates $B$

Comment: @Henry Correct, the only question is if the user knows these continuity arguments. That makes the answer below a lot more approachable for someone who doesn't, I think it's a lot better than a continuity argument.

Answer (score 1):

Some value $a$ is going to be plugged in for $x$.  If $-1\leq a \leq 1$, then look at each factor of $(a-1)(a+1)(a+2)$

Then $-2\leq a-1 \leq 0$ so this factor is negative or zero.

$0\leq a+1 \leq 2$ so this factor is positive or zero.

$1\leq a+2 \leq 3$ so this factor is positive.

If you multiply three such things together you either get $0$ or a negative.

Answer (score 1):

You have,
$$
y=(x^2-1)(x+2)
$$
For the given range of $a$, the factor $(x^2-1) $ is always negative or zero and clearly $y$ must be $\leq 0$. You can show by direct substitution that answers A,B, and C are allowed but D is not.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the definition of the graph of an equation (or of a function)? A point $(x,y)=(a,b)$ lies on the graph of an equation (or a function) if and only if the coordinates $(a,b)$, i.e. setting $x=a$ and $y=b$, satisfy the equation. For example, the point $(1.2,1.44)$ lies on the parabola $y=x^2$ because it satisfies the equation: plugging in $1.2$ for $x$ and $1.44$ for $y$ yields a true statement $1.44=1.2^2$.

Since in this question you're effectively given the equation of a function $y=f(x)$, where $f(x)=(x-1)(x+1)(x+2)$, the question is really asking what could (or rather, what could NOT) be the value of $b=f(a)$ if $-1\leqslant a\leqslant 1$. The key to answering this question is to determine the signs of this function on different intervals on the number line. See for example (I just did a quick search for what's available online, but the same topic is covered in any basic algebra textbook) the tutorials [here](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/Alg/SolvePolyInequalities.aspx) or [here](https://www.analyzemath.com/Inequalities_Polynomial/Inequalities_Polynomial_T.html) for solving such inequalities on the number line. Once you determine the sign of all outputs of this function $f(x)$ on this interval, you'll know the answer — because you'll see that only one of the answer choices is not a possible output $f(a)$ of this function when $a$ is in $[-1,1]$.